# Minimum applications and requirements to develop Asp.Net MVC5 application on Windows 7

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, azure

I have been trying to develop an Asp.Net MVC5 application that will use a database and uploaded to Azure but I can not seem to get all the dependencies. The template fails to be able to register a user.

Now I am to the point where I have to ask for help. Therefore I am here.

So my questions are: What exactly is required on a Windows 7 machine to be able to develop an Asp.Net MVC5 application and deploy to Azure for free? 
Is there a checklist which I can go through to make sure I have absolutely everything needed?

What I have so far: Visual Studio 2015 Community edition. A trial account on Azure with more than enough credit.
Some sql server installations that I am not sure are working or not.

I would be very grateful for anything that can help me isolate the problem.

EDIT:
What can I check for to make sure that I have everything needed to be able to run the template with the register functionality?

Here is the error message I get when trying to register a user:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a        connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.
>   )

Connection string (unmodified):

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TestWithSql-20151201053259.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TestWithSql-20151201053259;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Are you developing this locally on a Win7 machine?  Do you have a database to use?  I doubt it's an issue with minimum requirements or something like that - it's most likely a configuration issue or a code issue.

Comment: Yeah. I develop it on my personal laptop locally. I have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 installed and also Microsoft SQL Server 2016 CTP3.0.
I also used Web Platform Installer 5.0 to install all the web tools needed (supposedly). There was some bundle that I installed. I have not specified a database.

Comment: Are you registering the user in a database?  Then you need to specify a database in the connection string.

Comment: But that is the thing. I have developed on an already set up machine and it needed no other thing except to create the project. It had the register, log in, change password, and all those features right out of the template.

Comment: The project template may have done the setup work for you - but it won't do that when you deploy to Azure.  At least, it sounds like that's the issue here.

Comment: Tim, no I am not having issues with Azure, yet. 
I simply want to be able to run the template locally on my machine like I have done one a machine that had everything setup already.

Comment: Can you show the connection string and see if you are able to connect to your SQL Server from SQL Management Studio

Comment: I have not changed anything in the code from the template. How do I connect using the Management studio and that string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem above is you are referring to a local database. (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB refers to v12 of local db. On my system if I run at a cmd line

```
sqllocaldb i MSSQLLocalDB
```

I get

```
Name:               mssqllocaldb
Version:            12.0.2000.8
Shared name:
Owner:              MyMachine\Adam
Auto-create:        Yes
State:              Stopped
Last start time:    12/1/2015 9:09:18 PM
Instance pipe name:
```

It should get installed with VS 2015, however I've heard of a couple instances of people's installs not setting this up (not sure of the cause, user or otherwise). Install LocalDB from 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299
and you should be good to go.

Now when you want to deploy to Azure, make sure you understand this process (I was the 'friend' in this article ha): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818489.aspx

Comment: Yes! 
That is exactly what was missing apparently. I installed the localDB and now it works for me to create a completely new project. I can register and log in all out of the box with no changes to the template whatsoever. The funny thing is that now it also works when I publish it to Azure :D Which I find kinda weird. Before it worked NEITHER locally nor on Azure just because I did not have localDB installed on my machine. Thank you very much. I have been pulling my hair out of frustration.